# jQuery functions not responding after append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, append

I'm creating a series of div boxes that lets users add/remove items from each box with jQuery. I find that after I add a new element to a box, the click function I have bound to that element will not respond. Here's roughly what my code looks like:

```
$(".add").click(function() {
$("#targetbox").append("<span class='remove'>This element was added</span>");
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
alert("removing");
$(this).remove();
});
```

If I pre-populate #targetbox with items, they respond to the click function. It's only the items that are dynamically added that do not respond to the function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the click method directly to your newly appended element

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    $("#targetbox").append("<span class='remove'>This element was added</span>")
    .bind("click",function(e) {
        alert("removing");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Or use the `.live()` method that will bind the click event for you after appending any new `.remove` elements

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    $("#targetbox").append("<span class='remove'>This element was added</span>");
});

$(".remove").live("click", function() {
    alert("removing");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Didn't know about the "live()" method, that's pretty handy!

Answer (score 11):

Your code handles the click event for all elements *currently* in `$('.remove')`.
Any elements that do not exist yet are not affected.

You need to call the `.live()` or `.delegate` methods, which will handle the event for all elements that match the selector, no matter when they were created.

For example:

```
$(".remove").live('click', function() {
    alert("removing");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when your code runs, the items aren't added yet.  You need to add the remove click function to be dynamically assigned to your new  block after you add it during the add click function.

```
$(".add").click(function() {
  $("#targetbox").append("<span class='remove'>This element was added</span>");
  // Add code here for .remove click function
});
```