# unable to attach click event to li element using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am unable to get the click event for this HTML:

```
<ul id="frd_overlay_list">
<li><div class="divLink"><div id="1"><img src="path"><div class="frdName">Name</div></div></div></li>
<li><div class="divLink"><div id="2"><img src="path"><div class="frdName">Name</div></div></div></li>
</ul>
```

and JQuery script:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    console.log('Not working');
});
```

I am able to get click event for the ul element i.e.

```
$('ul#frd_overlay_list').click(function(){
    console.log('This works');
});
```

I have tried this, but this also doesnt work:

```
$('ul#frd_overlay_list li').click(function(){
    console.log('Doesn't work either');
});
```

Please give me pointers what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can  you paste ur complete html code once

Comment: Check it over here, http://jsfiddle.net/eY2cG/

Comment: your example works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your example works except for the last one:
You need to escape the `'` or use double quotes for the string

```
$('ul#frd_overlay_list li').click(function(){
    console.log("Doesn't work either");
});
```

Since you want to apply the click events for dynamically added elements, you could use `on` function of jQuery.

- `on` would bind event handlers for dynamically added elements
- `bind` would only bind event handlers for currently existing elements.

Usage of `on`:

```
$("ul#frd_overlay_list li").on("click", function(){
  console.log("Doesn't work either");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kg8EQ/2/)

Comment: thanks for the support... however the problem was not in this code. I am appending li elements dynamically, which I completely missed to consider. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369908/jquery-functions-not-responding-after-append. Thanks again to you all.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. You could use `on` instead of `bind`