# Symfony, Jquery & Ajax, appending elements that have been appended itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a jquery that appends row(s) of data in a table (the list selection) to another table. It works like you select an item or items (a row) you want to submit, and it duplicates itself to another area where you can submit.

Here is that jquery function :

```
$("#searchsub table tr").click(function(event) {
            if(event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
                $(":checkbox", this).trigger("click");
            }
        });

        $("#showsub input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highlightrow");
                $(this).attr("checked",true);
                var datarow = $(this).closest("tr.datarow");
                var row = datarow.clone();
                row.find(".select").html("<span class='delete'>&#215;</span>");
                $("#submitshipment #datarow").append(row);
            } else {
                $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("highlightrow");
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-id");
                var findRow = $("#datarow tr[data-id='" + index + "']");
                findRow.remove();
            }
        })

        $("#datarow").delegate("span.delete", "click", function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(100, function(){
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-id");
                var findRow = $("#showsub tr[data-id='"+index+"']");
                findRow.removeClass("highlightrow");
                findRow.find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", false);
            });
        })
```

So this works perfectly. When a user clicks on a row table with the listed data, it appends to another table where a user will submit a form once they are finished selecting the row(s).

However, when I populate data from an Ajax call (a search function) and append the results to the list, the above jquery doesn't apply anymore and it doesn't append when user selects it. Could it be that it's not recognizing an already appended element?

Here is the function:

```
$(".searchsubform form").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('log_searchdano') }}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"dano": $("#form_dano").val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#showsub tbody tr.original").remove();
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        var row = "<tr class='datarow' data-id='"+data[i].subid+"'>";
                        row += "<td><input type='hidden' name='searchsub[]' value='"+data[i].subid+"' />"+data[i].dano+"</td>";
                        row += "<td>"+data[i].partno+"</td>";
                        row += "<td>"+data[i].batchno+"</td>";
                        row += "<td>"+data[i].rackno+"</td>";
                        row += "<td>"+data[i].diecode+"</td>";
                        row += "<td>"+data[i].heatcode+"</td>";
                        row += "<td>"+data[i].inqty+"</td>";
                        row += "<td class='select'><input type='checkbox' id='subcheck' name='sub[]' value='"+data[i].subid+"' /></td>";
                        row += "</tr>";

                        $("#sublist table tbody").append(row);
                        $("#showsub td.select").closest("tr").addClass("original");
                    }

                }
            });
        })
```

EDIT: here is my html DOM:

http://pastebin.com/6KHiHV1w

Comment: JQuery events do not fire automatically upon 'appended' HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369908/jquery-functions-not-responding-after-append

Comment: @AlbertoGaona .live() is deprecated but when I changed to .on() it still isn't working.

Comment: Nevermind I got it! .delegate() is the way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. And I've already had the solution in the code.

```
$("#searchsub #showsub").delegate("tr", "click", function(event) {...
```

And

```
$("#showsub").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "change",function() {...
```